# Values passing to multiple conditionals in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, error-handling

I have a input field where I'm checking these two conditions...

1. If the input field is a valid email format
2. If the input field ends in a *specific* domain

   ```
   $('#newsletter_submit').on('click', function () {

     document.getElementById('newsletter_text').removeAttribute('required')
     var $emailFieldValue = $('#newsletter_text').val();
     var $splitEmailFieldValue = $emailFieldValue.split('@');
     var $result = $('#result')


     function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
       var pattern = /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;
       return pattern.test(emailAddress);
     }

     if (!isValidEmailAddress($emailFieldValue)) {
        $result.animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 0, function () {
         $(this).text('Must be a valid email format').css('color', 'red');
       }).animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 500);
       var obj = {}
       obj['$emailFieldValue'] = $emailFieldValue
       console.log('obj.$emailFieldValue', typeof obj.$emailFieldValue)
     if (($splitEmailFieldValue[1].toLowerCase()) !== 'acme.com')) {
         $result.animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 0, function () {
         $(this).text('Only Acme employees can register i.e. joe@acme.com').css('color', 'red');
       }).animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 500);
     }
     } else {
       $result.animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 0, function () {
         $(this).text('Thanks for registering').css('color', 'green');
       }).animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 500);
     }
   })
   ```

Currently it just ignores the domain specific conditional and allow one to enter `clark.kent@dailyplanet.com` and I get the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

Not sure why that is happening, as I checked:

```
 var obj = {}
     obj['$emailFieldValue'] = $emailFieldValue
     console.log('obj.$emailFieldValue', typeof obj.$emailFieldValue)
```

And get string?! But the error says undefined?

Comment: What is the console.log of `$splitEmailFieldValue`?

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for responding... String!

Comment: Uh, no, it's an array.  So logging it should print an array in the console.  What's it's value?  It should presumably print to the console `['clark.kent', 'dailyplanet.com']`

Comment: Also as a side note; from a security standpoint, restricting email domains should be done on the server side, not the client side.  Or **not only** the client side.  There are easy ways around your logic.

Comment: @Taplar Oh sorry I misread that...

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for that recommendation. Is it because it would be hard for users to  engage in malicious activity?

Comment: Users cannot tamper with your code server side.  They can easily intercept/change requests made from the browser before they reach your server.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks! I suppose through the input field itself?

Comment: They user doesn't hav to tamper with the field at all.  Like I said, they can intercept/change the requests them selves.  Either by replaying requests from the developer tools, or there are browser plugins that let developers tamper with requests.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for the 411. I'll follow up on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend splitting the validation and later do the validations, take a look.

```js
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
  }
  
function isValidDomainAddress(emailAddress) {
  return emailAddress.toLowerCase() === 'acme.com';
}

$('#newsletter_submit').on('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('newsletter_text').removeAttribute('required')
  var $emailFieldValue = $('#newsletter_text').val();
  var $splitEmailFieldValue = $emailFieldValue.split('@');
  var $result = $('#result');
  var isValid = isValidEmailAddress($emailFieldValue);
  if (!isValid) {
     $result.animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 0, function () {
      $($result).text('Must be a valid email format').css('color', 'red');
    }).animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 500);
  }
   var obj = {}
    obj['$emailFieldValue'] = $emailFieldValue
    console.log('obj.$emailFieldValue', typeof obj.$emailFieldValue);
  var isValidDomain = isValid? isValidDomainAddress($splitEmailFieldValue[1]): false;
  if (isValid && !isValidDomain) {
      $result.animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 0, function () {
      $(this).text('Only Acme employees can register i.e. joe@acme.com').css('color', 'red');
    }).animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 500);
  } 
  
  if(isValid && isValidDomain){
    $result.animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 0, function () {
      $(this).text('Thanks for registering').css('color', 'green');
    }).animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 500);
  }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="newsletter_text" required/>
<div id="result"></div>
<br/>
<button id="newsletter_submit" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Juan! This is what I wanted!